# getSheetByCodeName not working properly when VBE isn't open

Tags: excel, vba

I have my code running perfectly when VBE is open on the second screen, but it fails to find the sheet when VBE is closed, and displays the `MsgBox`.
The workbook that is being opened is pretty big and slow to open.
I added a `DoEvents` but that did not seem to make a difference.
Any clue ?

```
'some code.....
Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(filename:=filename, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
DoEvents
Set shSrc = getSheetByCodeName(wbSrc, "Sheet3")    
If shSrc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Couldn't find sheet"
    Exit Sub
End If
'continues....


Function getSheetByCodeName(wb As Workbook, codeName As String) As Worksheet
'given wb object and codeName string, returns a ref to the sheet in wb that has that codeName
'returns Nothing if nothing found
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If sh.codeName = codeName Then
            Set getSheetByCodeName = sh
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sh
    Set getSheetByCodeName = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I would try to debug by adding `Debug.Print sh.codeName` into the loop, and check the sheets count first.

Comment: I just checked the code on my PC and it seems to run fine.
Maybe try `wb.Worksheets` instead of `wb.Sheets`

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing this `Set shSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets("Sheet3")` instead of using a function to do the same?

Comment: @DarXyde: not the same at all. Your example uses sheet.name, mine uses sheet.codeName, which is not impacted by user changing the sheet.name every month.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez my bad, I must be blind or something. Well, tested with 2 workbooks and VBA editor closed, it runs fine. This probably doesn't help much, but maybe the workbook doesn't open quick enough or might have other events on open that break your current script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary answer (before a better one):
since users WILL change the sheet name every month and since getSheetByCodeName seems to pose an issue with that specific file, I decided to use

```
Set shSrc = wbSrc.Sheets(3)   'use index property
```

This is going to work as long as the users don't move the tab.